# Replace string with link to overlap

Tags: c#, php, html, asp.net-mvc

I have to replace string in comment with link to overlap. There's code in PHP:

```
$comment = str_replace('[%account]','<a href="'.$doc_root.'/basket/?idsession='.$idsession.'">account</a>',$comment);
```

And I need to to the same thing in C#, eventually in HTML, becouse is  ASP.NET MVC app. I know there's a method called Replace(string OldValue, string NewValue), but I believe it is only for string type, not for links. Or Am I wrong? Any ideas?
I trie to do it with class property like this:

```
 public string AccountLink { get { return "account"; }  }
```

and then:

```
parcel.Comment = parcelStatus.Comment.Replace("[%account]", parcel.AccountLink)
```

But I don't know how to connect the word "account" with that link from PHP code above.

Comment: how about using _regex_ ?

Comment: Your code looks to only be using strings, so `Replace` would work, surely? Or do you mean because you are using `@Html.ActionLink` in an MVC view? If so you could use `@Url.Action` to product the url and place that in your own A tag in your markup

Comment: All I need to do the same thing as it is in PHP code above. I need a clickable link "account" when the comment showing up, just replace [%account] with link account, that's all. How to use this "Regex"?